# How get data on calendar when you click the point

Tags: anychart

I'm using calendar from AnyChart 8.10, and I'm looking to get the date when I click on the point in the calendar. I use the function below but I have no data back.

```
        chart.listen('Click', function(e) {
           console.log(e.getData("value"));  
        });
```

Thanks
Best regards

Answer (score 1):

Looking into `e.target` properties, I found this:

```js
anychart.onDocumentLoad(() => {
  let data = [
    { x: "2020-01-12", value: "6" },
    { x: "2020-01-15", value: "2" },
    { x: "2020-01-18", value: "2" },
    { x: "2020-01-19", value: "5" },
    { x: "2020-02-03", value: "1" },
    { x: "2020-02-19", value: "9" },
    { x: "2020-03-19", value: "2" }
  ];

  let chart = anychart.calendar(data);

  chart.container("container");
  
  chart.listen("click", e => {
    let el = e.target.Ii; // <--- HERE
    
    if (el) {
      console.log(`Date: ${el.x}`);
      console.log(`Value: ${el.value}`);
    }
  });
  
  chart.draw();
});
```

```css
#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 350px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.anychart.com/releases/8.10.0/js/anychart-core.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.anychart.com/releases/8.10.0/js/anychart-calendar.min.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

My sample data is from the documentation: [Calendar Chart | Basic Charts | AnyChart Documentation](https://docs.anychart.com/Basic_Charts/Calendar_Chart#quick_start)

Answer (score 0):

AnyChart Version 8.12.0 introduced pointClick to interact with the Calendar chart’s elements.

```
chart.listen("pointClick", function(e) {
  console.log(e);
});
```

This code listens for clicks on chart dates and logs the event information to the console. You can use this information for various actions.

See a [complex calendar chart example](https://playground.anychart.com/dLR7T9Ym/0) in the Playground Demo

Learn more:

- [Event Listeners Documentation](https://docs.anychart.com/Common_Settings/Event_Listeners)
- [Calendar chart tutorial](https://www.anychart.com/blog/2024/03/04/javascript-calendar-charts/) (including elements click)